# How to disable user's input and escape of the loop when user act in c#?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

today I have very simple question that I know probably it will have bad feedback. I want to get out of a loop that disable user input on a console application using c#. I have this:

```
while (true) {
            Console.ReadKey (true);
        }
        string key = Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
            if (key.ToUpper() == "F10") {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello!");
        }
```

Basicly, I want to disable the user of writing on the console but I want that when the user press F10 something happens.

Thank you for your time. Bye.

Comment: This is an infinite loop.

Comment: What triggers a "break out" of the loop? If that is missing, the loop will never end. Thus: an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bool userInput = true;

while (userInput) {
            Console.ReadKey (true);
            string key = Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
            if (key.ToUpper() == "F10") {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello!");
            userInput = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In C# `boolean` keyword doesn't exist. `bool` and `Boolean` exists. Also this is an infinite loop.

Comment: Woops, too used to java haha. And yes I see now, should have the whole if statement inside the while loop right?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the input from your first `Console.ReadKey()` to see if it's `F10`. You can then make a Boolean to check if `F10` was hit and apply it to your `while` loop, like this:

```
bool restrictInput = true;
while (restrictInput)
{
    string key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key.ToString();
    if (key.ToUpper() == "F10")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        restrictInput = false;
    }
}
```

You can also use `break;` in place of `restrictInput = false;` which would take you out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    while (true)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine(input.Key.ToString() + " pressed");
            if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.F10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Breaking loop.");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
while (true)
{
    if(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F10)
          Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop unless terminated by `Ctrl + C`. OP wants to terminate the loop when `F10` is pressed.

Comment: According to his specification he wants to:
1. "...disable the user of writing on the console..."
2. "...when the user press F10 something happens."

Comment: The user input is still enabled. Keep pressing `F10` and you'll keep seeing `Hello!` on the console.

Comment: He specifies he wants to "...disable the user of **writing** on the console..." not input itself. Otherwise he would not ask F10 to perform a function.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try this.